# Cannot display google map on vue cli component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google map api to create a simple application with vue.js. The api key works if I use it with simple html and javascript, but if I move the same process to vue no map appears and no errors appear in the console, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

In the project's index.html file I integrate the api url as follows:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=MY_API_KEY"></script>
```

**Vue component**

```
<template>
 <div>
  <h3>Here comes the map</h3>
<div ref="map" id="map"></div>
 <button @click="getMap">Show the map</button>
</div>
```

```
getMap() {

    const uluru = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036 };
    const map = new window.google.maps.Map(this.$refs['map'],{

         zoom: 15,
         center: uluru,
         mapTypeID: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       }

return map;
}
```

In vue cli to call up the google map object I have to add **window** otherwise it gives me an error.

```
new window.google.maps.Map()...instead of new google.maps.Map()
```

As explained the code below does not display the map and does not report any errors on the console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you set correct Api key instead of `key=MY_API_KEY`.
Second, add some styles `#map {height: 450px;}`, by default `<div ref="map" id="map"></div>` has `height = 0`